# Sharpen on a Bitmap using C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap

I want to put a sharpen filter on an image. I have found a web [with short tutorial](http://www.student.kuleuven.be/~m0216922/CG/filtering.html).
I tried to do it in C# so here is my code. Anyway, I tried to find out why it is not working. I do not know if I am doing something wrong, if yes, please advise me what to do to make it work as it should be. Thanks

```
        public static Bitmap sharpen(Bitmap image)
    {
        Bitmap sharpenImage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);

        int filterWidth = 3;
        int filterHeight = 3;
        int w = image.Width;
        int h = image.Height;

        double[,] filter = new double[filterWidth, filterHeight];

        filter[0, 0] = filter[0, 1] = filter[0, 2] = filter[1, 0] = filter[1, 2] = filter[2, 0] = filter[2, 1] = filter[2, 2] = -1;
        filter[1, 1] = 9;

        double factor = 1.0;
        double bias = 0.0;

        Color[,] result = new Color[image.Width, image.Height];

        for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y)
            {
                double red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0;
                Color imageColor = image.GetPixel(x, y);

                for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterWidth; filterX++)
                {
                    for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterHeight; filterY++)
                    {
                        int imageX = (x - filterWidth / 2 + filterX + w) % w;
                        int imageY = (y - filterHeight / 2 + filterY + h) % h;
                        red += imageColor.R * filter[filterX, filterY];
                        green += imageColor.G * filter[filterX, filterY];
                        blue += imageColor.B * filter[filterX, filterY];
                    }
                    int r = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * red + bias), 0), 255);
                    int g = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * green + bias), 0), 255);
                    int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * blue + bias), 0), 255);

                    result[x, y] = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j)
            {
                sharpenImage.SetPixel(i, j, result[i, j]);
            }
        }
        return sharpenImage;
    }
```

Comment: There is interesting chapter of "Beautiful code" written by Charles Petzold named "On-the-Fly Code Generation for Image Processing". You may find it very useful.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap sharpen(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap sharpenImage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);

    int filterWidth = 3;
    int filterHeight = 3;
    int w = image.Width;
    int h = image.Height;

    double[,] filter = new double[filterWidth, filterHeight];

    filter[0, 0] = filter[0, 1] = filter[0, 2] = filter[1, 0] = filter[1, 2] = filter[2, 0] = filter[2, 1] = filter[2, 2] = -1;
    filter[1, 1] = 9;

    double factor = 1.0;
    double bias = 0.0;

    Color[,] result = new Color[image.Width, image.Height];

    for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y)
        {
            double red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0;

//=====[REMOVE LINES]========================================================
// Color must be read per filter entry, not per image pixel.
            Color imageColor = image.GetPixel(x, y);
//===========================================================================

            for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterWidth; filterX++)
            {
                for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterHeight; filterY++)
                {
                    int imageX = (x - filterWidth / 2 + filterX + w) % w;
                    int imageY = (y - filterHeight / 2 + filterY + h) % h;

//=====[INSERT LINES]========================================================
// Get the color here - once per fiter entry and image pixel.
                    Color imageColor = image.GetPixel(imageX, imageY);
//===========================================================================

                    red += imageColor.R * filter[filterX, filterY];
                    green += imageColor.G * filter[filterX, filterY];
                    blue += imageColor.B * filter[filterX, filterY];
                }
                int r = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * red + bias), 0), 255);
                int g = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * green + bias), 0), 255);
                int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * blue + bias), 0), 255);

                result[x, y] = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j)
        {
            sharpenImage.SetPixel(i, j, result[i, j]);
        }
    }
    return sharpenImage;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

I took Daniel's answer and modified it for performance, by using BitmapData class, since using GetPixel/SetPixel is very expensive and inappropriate for performance-hungry systems. It works exactly the same as the previous solution and can be used instead.

```
   public static Bitmap Sharpen(Bitmap image)
    {
        Bitmap sharpenImage = (Bitmap)image.Clone();

        int filterWidth = 3;
        int filterHeight = 3;
        int width = image.Width;
        int height = image.Height;

        // Create sharpening filter.
        double[,] filter = new double[filterWidth, filterHeight];
        filter[0, 0] = filter[0, 1] = filter[0, 2] = filter[1, 0] = filter[1, 2] = filter[2, 0] = filter[2, 1] = filter[2, 2] = -1;
        filter[1, 1] = 9;

        double factor = 1.0;
        double bias = 0.0;

        Color[,] result = new Color[image.Width, image.Height];

        // Lock image bits for read/write.
        BitmapData pbits = sharpenImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
        int bytes = pbits.Stride * height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pbits.Scan0, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

        int rgb;
        // Fill the color array with the new sharpened color values.
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                double red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0;

                for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterWidth; filterX++)
                {
                    for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterHeight; filterY++)
                    {
                        int imageX = (x - filterWidth / 2 + filterX + width) % width;
                        int imageY = (y - filterHeight / 2 + filterY + height) % height;

                        rgb = imageY * pbits.Stride + 3 * imageX;

                        red += rgbValues[rgb + 2] * filter[filterX, filterY];
                        green += rgbValues[rgb + 1] * filter[filterX, filterY];
                        blue += rgbValues[rgb + 0] * filter[filterX, filterY];
                    }
                    int r = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * red + bias), 0), 255);
                    int g = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * green + bias), 0), 255);
                    int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * blue + bias), 0), 255);

                    result[x, y] = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                }
            }
        }

        // Update the image with the sharpened pixels.
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                rgb = y * pbits.Stride + 3 * x;

                rgbValues[rgb + 2] = result[x, y].R;
                rgbValues[rgb + 1] = result[x, y].G;
                rgbValues[rgb + 0] = result[x, y].B;
            }
        }

        // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, pbits.Scan0, bytes);
        // Release image bits.
        sharpenImage.UnlockBits(pbits);

        return sharpenImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

This will create a softer sharpening effect. You can expand the filter array if you need to, or change the 16 to something larger, but I found this isn't as harsh as the one you have.

```
const int filterWidth = 5;
const int filterHeight = 5;

double[,] filter = new double[filterWidth,filterHeight] {
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
    { -1,  2,  2,  2, -1 },
    { -1,  2,  16,  2, -1 },
    { -1,  2,  2,  2, -1 },
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 }
};

double factor = 1.0 / 16.0;
```

Answer (score 4):

I combined niaher's and David's answer and fixed the "bias" property. Now you can pass a "strength" between 0.0 and 1.0 to the Sharpen() function.

```
/// <summary>
///     Sharpens the specified image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">The image.</param>
/// <param name="strength">The strength between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Bitmap Sharpen(Image image, double strength)
{
    using (var bitmap = image as Bitmap)
    {
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            var sharpenImage = bitmap.Clone() as Bitmap;

            int width = image.Width;
            int height = image.Height;

            // Create sharpening filter.
            const int filterWidth = 5;
            const int filterHeight = 5;

            var filter = new double[,]
                {
                    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
                    {-1,  2,  2,  2, -1},
                    {-1,  2, 16,  2, -1},
                    {-1,  2,  2,  2, -1},
                    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1}
                };

            double bias = 1.0 - strength;
            double factor = strength/16.0;

            var result = new Color[image.Width,image.Height];

            // Lock image bits for read/write.
            if (sharpenImage != null)
            {
                BitmapData pbits = sharpenImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                                                            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                            PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

                // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                int bytes = pbits.Stride*height;
                var rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

                // Copy the RGB values into the array.
                Marshal.Copy(pbits.Scan0, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

                int rgb;
                // Fill the color array with the new sharpened color values.
                for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
                    {
                        double red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0;

                        for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterWidth; filterX++)
                        {
                            for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterHeight; filterY++)
                            {
                                int imageX = (x - filterWidth/2 + filterX + width)%width;
                                int imageY = (y - filterHeight/2 + filterY + height)%height;

                                rgb = imageY*pbits.Stride + 3*imageX;

                                red += rgbValues[rgb + 2]*filter[filterX, filterY];
                                green += rgbValues[rgb + 1]*filter[filterX, filterY];
                                blue += rgbValues[rgb + 0]*filter[filterX, filterY];
                            }

                            rgb = y*pbits.Stride + 3*x;

                            int r = Math.Min(Math.Max((int) (factor*red + (bias*rgbValues[rgb + 2])), 0), 255);
                            int g = Math.Min(Math.Max((int) (factor*green + (bias*rgbValues[rgb + 1])), 0), 255);
                            int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int) (factor*blue + (bias*rgbValues[rgb + 0])), 0), 255);

                            result[x, y] = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Update the image with the sharpened pixels.
                for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
                    {
                        rgb = y*pbits.Stride + 3*x;

                        rgbValues[rgb + 2] = result[x, y].R;
                        rgbValues[rgb + 1] = result[x, y].G;
                        rgbValues[rgb + 0] = result[x, y].B;
                    }
                }

                // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap.
                Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, pbits.Scan0, bytes);
                // Release image bits.
                sharpenImage.UnlockBits(pbits);
            }

            return sharpenImage;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, fixed the problem with distored edges. Here´s the updated one:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sharpens the specified image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">The image.</param>
/// <param name="strength">The strength.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Bitmap Sharpen(Image image, double strength)
{
    using (var bitmap = image as Bitmap)
    {
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            var sharpenImage = bitmap.Clone() as Bitmap;

            int width = image.Width;
            int height = image.Height;

            // Create sharpening filter.
            const int filterSize = 5;

            var filter = new double[,]
                {
                    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
                    {-1,  2,  2,  2, -1},
                    {-1,  2, 16,  2, -1},
                    {-1,  2,  2,  2, -1},
                    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1}
                };

            double bias = 1.0 - strength;
            double factor = strength/16.0;

            const int s = filterSize/2;

            var result = new Color[image.Width,image.Height];

            // Lock image bits for read/write.
            if (sharpenImage != null)
            {
                BitmapData pbits = sharpenImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                                                            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                            PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

                // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                int bytes = pbits.Stride*height;
                var rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

                // Copy the RGB values into the array.
                Marshal.Copy(pbits.Scan0, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

                int rgb;
                // Fill the color array with the new sharpened color values.
                for (int x = s; x < width - s; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = s; y < height - s; y++)
                    {
                        double red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0;

                        for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterSize; filterX++)
                        {
                            for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterSize; filterY++)
                            {
                                int imageX = (x - s + filterX + width)%width;
                                int imageY = (y - s + filterY + height)%height;

                                rgb = imageY*pbits.Stride + 3*imageX;

                                red += rgbValues[rgb + 2]*filter[filterX, filterY];
                                green += rgbValues[rgb + 1]*filter[filterX, filterY];
                                blue += rgbValues[rgb + 0]*filter[filterX, filterY];
                            }

                            rgb = y * pbits.Stride + 3 * x;

                            int r = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * red + (bias * rgbValues[rgb + 2])), 0), 255);
                            int g = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * green + (bias * rgbValues[rgb + 1])), 0), 255);
                            int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * blue + (bias * rgbValues[rgb + 0])), 0), 255);

                            result[x, y] = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Update the image with the sharpened pixels.
                for (int x = s; x < width - s; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = s; y < height - s; y++)
                    {
                        rgb = y*pbits.Stride + 3*x;

                        rgbValues[rgb + 2] = result[x, y].R;
                        rgbValues[rgb + 1] = result[x, y].G;
                        rgbValues[rgb + 0] = result[x, y].B;
                    }
                }

                // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap.
                Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, pbits.Scan0, bytes);
                // Release image bits.
                sharpenImage.UnlockBits(pbits);
            }

            return sharpenImage;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The updated code has the result calculation inside the FilterX loop; Move the "rgb =" block down past the closing brace below it.

Answer (score 2):

hi i edit the code a litle bit and add two other matrices
for me this works now perfect

```
/// <summary>
    /// Sharpens the specified image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The image.</param>
    /// <param name="strength">strength erwartet werte zwische 0 - 99</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Bitmap Sharpen(Image image, whichMatrix welcheMatrix , double strength)
    {
        double FaktorKorrekturWert = 0;

        //strenght muß für den jeweiligen filter angepasst werden
        switch (welcheMatrix)
        {
            case whichMatrix.Gaussian3x3:
                //diese Matrix benötigt einen strenght Wert von 0 bis -9.9 default ist -2.5
                //und einen korekturwert von 16
                strength = (strength * -1) / 10;
                FaktorKorrekturWert = 16;
                break;

            case whichMatrix.Mean3x3:
                //diese Matrix benötigt einen strenght Wert von 0 bis -9 default ist -2.25
                //und einen Korrekturwert von 10
                strength = strength * -9 / 100;
                FaktorKorrekturWert = 10;
                break;

            case whichMatrix.Gaussian5x5Type1:
                //diese Matrix benötigt einen strenght Wert von 0 bis 2.5 default ist 1.25
                //und einen Korrekturwert von 12
                strength = strength * 2.5 / 100;
                FaktorKorrekturWert = 12;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        using (var bitmap = image as Bitmap)
        {
            if (bitmap != null)
            {
                var sharpenImage = bitmap.Clone() as Bitmap;

                int width = image.Width;
                int height = image.Height;

                // Create sharpening filter.
                var filter = Matrix(welcheMatrix);

                //const int filterSize = 3; // wenn die Matrix 3 Zeilen und 3 Spalten besitzt dann 3 bei 4 = 4 usw.                    
                int filterSize = filter.GetLength(0);                   

                double bias = 1.0 - strength;
                double factor = strength / FaktorKorrekturWert;

                //const int s = filterSize / 2;
                int s = filterSize / 2; // Filtersize ist keine Constante mehr darum wurde der befehl const entfernt


                var result = new Color[image.Width, image.Height];

                // Lock image bits for read/write.
                if (sharpenImage != null)
                {
                    BitmapData pbits = sharpenImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

                    // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                    int bytes = pbits.Stride * height;
                    var rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

                    // Copy the RGB values into the array.
                    Marshal.Copy(pbits.Scan0, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

                    int rgb;
                    // Fill the color array with the new sharpened color values.
                    for (int x = s; x < width - s; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = s; y < height - s; y++)
                        {
                            double red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0;

                            for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterSize; filterX++)
                            {
                                for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterSize; filterY++)
                                {
                                    int imageX = (x - s + filterX + width) % width;
                                    int imageY = (y - s + filterY + height) % height;

                                    rgb = imageY * pbits.Stride + 3 * imageX;

                                    red += rgbValues[rgb + 2] * filter[filterX, filterY];
                                    green += rgbValues[rgb + 1] * filter[filterX, filterY];
                                    blue += rgbValues[rgb + 0] * filter[filterX, filterY];
                                }

                                rgb = y * pbits.Stride + 3 * x;

                                int r = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * red + (bias * rgbValues[rgb + 2])), 0), 255);
                                int g = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * green + (bias * rgbValues[rgb + 1])), 0), 255);
                                int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * blue + (bias * rgbValues[rgb + 0])), 0), 255);

                                result[x, y] = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Update the image with the sharpened pixels.
                    for (int x = s; x < width - s; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = s; y < height - s; y++)
                        {
                            rgb = y * pbits.Stride + 3 * x;

                            rgbValues[rgb + 2] = result[x, y].R;
                            rgbValues[rgb + 1] = result[x, y].G;
                            rgbValues[rgb + 0] = result[x, y].B;
                        }
                    }

                    // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap.
                    Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, pbits.Scan0, bytes);
                    // Release image bits.
                    sharpenImage.UnlockBits(pbits);
                }

                return sharpenImage;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public enum whichMatrix
    {
        Gaussian3x3,
        Mean3x3,
        Gaussian5x5Type1
    }


    private double[,] Matrix(whichMatrix welcheMatrix)
    {
        double[,] selectedMatrix = null;

        switch (welcheMatrix)
        {
            case whichMatrix.Gaussian3x3:
                selectedMatrix = new double[,]
                { 
                    { 1, 2, 1, }, 
                    { 2, 4, 2, }, 
                    { 1, 2, 1, }, 
                };
                break;

            case whichMatrix.Gaussian5x5Type1:
                selectedMatrix = new double[,]
                { 
                    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
                    {-1,  2,  2,  2, -1},
                    {-1,  2,  16, 2, -1},
                    {-1,  2, -1,  2, -1},
                    {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1} 
                };
                break;

            case whichMatrix.Mean3x3:
                selectedMatrix =new double[,]
                { 
                    { 1, 1, 1, }, 
                    { 1, 1, 1, }, 
                    { 1, 1, 1, }, 
                };
                break;
        }

        return selectedMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: aaalter edit coden in deutsch und englisch gleichezitig?
schlechte idee^^