# OpenCV does not contain definition for 'GetPixel'

Tags: c#, opencv, filter, emgucv

Trying to implement a filter on an image using OpenCv/EmguCV, getting the error:

Emgu.CV.Image does not contain a definition for 'GetPixel'

```
 for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterWidth; filterX++)
              {
                  for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterHeight; filterY++)
                  {
                      int imageX = (x - filterWidth / 2 + filterX + w) % w;
                      int imageY = (y - filterHeight / 2 + filterY + h) % h;

                      **Color imageColor = img.GetPixel(imageX, imageY);**
                      red += imageColor.R * filter[filterX, filterY];
                      green += imageColor.G * filter[filterX, filterY];
                      blue += imageColor.B * filter[filterX, filterY];
                  }
                  int r = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * red + bias), 0), 255);
                  int g = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * green + bias), 0), 255);
                  int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * blue + bias), 0), 255);

                  result[x, y] = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
              }
          }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j)
          {
              sharpenImage.SetPixel(i, j, result[i, j]);
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: The error is correct based on the API Documentation: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/Index.html. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

EMGU uses a struct built in C# to hold the image data. This allows the code to work more efficiently than using OpenCV for everything. While EMGU does wrap some OpenCV functions in unmanaged code, thus why we add the opencv.dll it also tries to keep as many functions as possible in c#.

EMGU Image Structure acces image data a little differently using the GetPixel method looks like this:

```
//Colour Image
Bgr my_Bgr = My_Image[0, 0];

//Gray Image
Gray my_Gray = gray_image[0, 0];
```

Where you obviously change [0,0] to the relevant location within you image. This is not recommended in EMGU as while it is not as slow as the Bitmap.GetPixel method it is still not the quickest method.

EMGU Image structure has direct access to the matrix of the image in the Image.Data property. This is much quicker at reading/writing data. However a small warning any method slows down considerably when looping through every pixel when the ROI of the image is set. It is much easier to manually set the for loop starting and finishing statements the required ROI setting then set the ROI field. The reason simply is that any method must first check the ROI then calculate the pixel being accesses before finding the data and this adds a couple of instructions.

The Image.Data method can be accessed like this:

```
//Image<Bgr,Byte>: Bgr = Blue,Green,Red

int Red = My_Image.Data[0,0,2]; //Read to the Red Spectrum
int Green= My_Image.Data[0,0,1]; //Read to the Green Spectrum
int Blue= My_Image.Data[0,0,0]; //Read to the BlueSpectrum
```

Anyway your code should look something more like this:

```
for (int filterX = 0; filterX < filterWidth; filterX++)
{
    for (int filterY = 0; filterY < filterHeight; filterY++)
    {
        int imageX = (x - filterWidth / 2 + filterX + w) % w;
        int imageY = (y - filterHeight / 2 + filterY + h) % h;

        red += img.Data[imageY,imageX,2] * filter[filterX, filterY];
        green += img.Data[imageY,imageX,1]  * filter[filterX, filterY];
        blue += img.Data[imageY,imageX,0]  * filter[filterX, filterY];
    }
    int r = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * red + bias), 0), 255);
    int g = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * green + bias), 0), 255);
    int b = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)(factor * blue + bias), 0), 255);

    result[x, y] = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
}
```

If you would like more help I cover the subject of accessing image data a little more in my code project article [Creating Your First EMGU Image Processing Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EMGU_Image_Processing.aspx),

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

This is broken down to the Filter2D you will need to navigate the support sites wiki to find exactly what you need..  http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/Index.html look at the CvInvoke..::..cvFilter2D Method or CvInvoke Class

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to apply the sharpen filter from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903632/sharpen-on-a-bitmap-using-c-sharp) question.
Since you are using EmguCV you probably don't want to be doing that - it will be much slower than using unsharp masking. However if you really want to - the EmguCV Image class exposes a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` property as `Bitmap` which will make your code work (very slowly).

So, change that line to read `Color imageColor = img.Bitmap.GetPixel(imageX, imageY);`