# Effecient algorithms for image pixel manipulations

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

Is there any efficient method to access and change image pixels than the usual scanning the pixel array and changing them? I've a psuedocode but I want a a better method than this. I just need an algorithm, any language is fine. It looks something like this:-

```
   For i in range(0,len(pixel_array),4)
       pixel_array[0] = a   //a is some random value
       pixel_array[1] = a
       pixel_array[2] = a
       pixel_array[3] = 1
```

Comment: Often you can find a library that uses hand optimized code and/or [SIMD instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) to do operations on an entire image at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem once, while i was moving pixels around in an SDL_Texture. There is not really any better option for you to do this, unless you tell us, what exactly you want to to. Do you have to manipulate pixel per pixel or can you set complete areas in one (e.g. if you draw a line, you could use memset to set a whole range in the array to that data)? You need to check, what could be done any faster. Drawing a rectangle can be optimized by editing the pixels in a bulk. But if you really need to change every pixel independently, then, no, there isnt any faster attempt besides doing it on the GPU instead of the CPU (e.g. using OpenGL).

Comment: I basically want to create filters, like greyscale filter takes average of all the rgb component and assign that to each subpixel. And it is  applied to the entire image area.

Comment: You could for example have a look at the GIMP Sourcecode how the greyscale filter works. But basically, yes, you have to iterate over every pixel. Take a look at this ressource to get a overview of some Grayscale algorithms: http://www.tannerhelland.com/3643/grayscale-image-algorithm-vb6/

Comment: All these algorithms use iteration over every pixel :( Ok If I want to make a filter like sharpening image which uses convolution, Is there a better algo for that instead of this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903632/sharpen-on-a-bitmap-using-c-sharp