# How to add System.Drawing in xamarin?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, system.drawing

I am trying for some time now to add System.Drawing to the references in Visual Studio 2015. Nothing seems to work. When I go into the add reference pane, there is no System.Drawing in the list.

I need the Bitmap class from System.Drawing not one from Android.Graphics

Comment: System.Drawing is not implemented on Android.  That is a Windows library that relies on Windows.  Android has a comparable drawing library.  You cannot use the System.Drawing Bitmap class.  What do you need to do that Android Bitmap does not support?

Comment: I need to sharpen an image and the algorithms that i found were writen for Bitmap from System.Drawing not Android.Graphics

Comment: check this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848720/how-to-sharpen-a-bitmap?noredirect=1#comment57437789_34848720

Comment: Made a comment on your other question that should help clear up the troubles there.  Regards.

Answer (score 2):

As @Cheesebaron quoted once if forum :

> If you look at
>   http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/assemblies you
>   will see that System.Drawing is not a part of the Assemblies shipped
>   with Xamarin.Android, the same goes for Xamarin.iOS.
>
> You will need to use the Android counterparts to filter images.

---

The alternative method is to add `System.Drawing.dll` as references.

Right click on `References` --> `Edit References` --> `.Net Assembly` --> `Browse...` --> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` --> select `System.Drawing.dll`.

Now try to make use of `Bitmap` class `using System.Drawing;`

[image]