# How to overcome the issue on installing Selenium WebDriver in Xamarin mobile application?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2017, appium-android

I try to download Selenium.WebDriver throught the NuGet Solution but i get the following error:

```
Failed to add reference. The package 'Selenium.WebDriver' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.Drawing' which was not found in the GAC.
```

I get the same error like above when i install Appium in xamarin, hence anyone can share me idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Selenium.WebDriver is designed to automate a browsers on Windows, not browsers within mobile devices (and thus not Xamarin application projects for iOS or Android) If you are looking to drive mobile browsers, you should look at Appium that does use the WebDriver protocol to test/automate device browsers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add System.Drawing in xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862868/how-to-add-system-drawing-in-xamarin)

Comment: @SushiHangover , thanks but i try to download appium , i get the same error too , so any solution can suggested?

Comment: @shijietio you do not add appium to your xamarin project. You should edit your question and state what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit your `.csproj` file.

   1. In visual studio you can "unload" the project, then right click on the unloaded project and you'll be able to edit.
2. Find the `ItemGroup` that contains references and edit it to include this line

   1. `<Reference Include="System.Drawing" />`

Something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="WebDriver, Version=3.141.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```