# How to make one image be the same sharp as another one?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, imagefilter

I have two images A and B. For example, A is the starry night picture of Van Gogh and B is a photograph of a room produced by modern cameras.

Obviously, B is sharper than A. 
Now I want to make Van Gogh's picture be the same sharp as B. I know mathematically gradient can describe the sharpness of one image, But How to calculate and use the gradient in this scenario specifically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to sharpen images?

Comment: Yes, I want to sharpen the image based on the sharpness of another one.

Comment: Basically, you want a sharpen image filter, so see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903632/sharpen-on-a-bitmap-using-c-sharp#903740

Comment: But I want to sharpen the image towards a target image,  that is to make the two images have the similarity in LBP for example.

Comment: this question is way too broad. what do you expect us to write as an answer? a 100 page phd thesis that covers any possible scenario? there is no general definition of sharpness that suits every image. and how does it even make any sense to match the "sharpness" of a picture and a painting?

Comment: I want to make one image have a similar LBP distribution as another one, that is enough.@Piglet

Comment: Good luck with that!